# Validation is preventing OnClick from firing

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I have made a simple feedback form. I click the submit button, the email sends ok and everything is good. So, I decided to add Google recaptcha to the page.
When I enclose the method in the validate check -

```
if (ctrlGoogleReCaptcha.Validate()) {//onclick method here//}
```

the OnClick no longer fires at all. It doesn't even get far enough to hit the breakpoint I put in.  If I take out the validate check it works again. I even tried a basic

```
if (Page.IsValid)
```

and that doesn't work either.

EDIT -

Here's the control on the page:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col-md-12">
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label"></asp:Label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-push-2">
<re:recaptchav2 SiteKey="xxxx" SecretKey="xxx" ErrorMessage="Human validation failed!" ID="recaptchaControl" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col-md-12">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light deep-purple">Contact us</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</div>

protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text, "siteinfo@onstagetonight.co.uk");
            mm.Subject = "Feedback from website";
            mm.Body = "Email from " + txtName.Text + "<br /><br />" + txtMessage.Text;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "mail.websitelive.net";
            smtp.Send(mm);
            panContact.Visible = false;
            panContactThanks.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            panContactFail.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

In the web.config, there is this line

```
<system.web>
<pages>
<controls>
<add assembly="recaptchav2" namespace="recaptchav2" tagPrefix="re" />
</controls>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

There is also recaptchav2.dll in the references.  This is all taken from an earlier version of the site in which it works. Once I copied it to my new site, in which only the design has changed, it no longer works. I fill in the form, click the "I'm not a robot", but when I click submit, nothing happens, it's like the OnClick event doesn't even exist.

Comment: Please show your code as to how and where you are binding the Captcha Control to the page. Assuming you use the [GoogleReCaptcha](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/884193/Google-ReCaptcha-ASP-net-Control) library

Comment: I've added some code above.